# Possible to get an HTML span element to word-wrap when inside a pre element?

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have an issue where I have `span` elements that are `absolute`ly positioned (they are call-outs). They are typically a single line, but sometimes need to wrap. That works fine. I set a width and they automatically wrap. ***Unless*** they are within a `pre` element.

Here's a [jsfiddle showing the above](http://jsfiddle.net/4bWDx/). I've tried changing the `display` to `block` or `inline-block`. I've tried setting `word-wrap` to `break-word`. Nothing seems to work.

I can try changing the `span` to a `div`, I guess semantically that makes sense too... but that requires a lot more time than I have now to deal with through my app.

I'm perfectly happy with an html5 or css3 solution that only works on the latest browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you just need to add following to your CSS

```
pre{
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to preformat your `pre`, add `white-space: normal;` to your CSS for that element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4bWDx/6/

`white-space: pre-wrap` gives different results, which may or may not be what you really want in your application. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4bWDx/9/ -- Try both out and see what you prefer.

Comment: I do need to preserve white-space, which is the whole reason I used the `pre` tag. Thanks for the link to more information on `white-space`

Answer (score 0):

Tried this one:

```
white-space:pre;
```

worked for me